# ModuleNotFoundError : No Module named 'tests'

Tags: python, pycharm, python-unittest

I have a test automation project where so far everything was working great.
I was able to run all the test by setting the Python path by typing the below command:

```
set PYTHONPATH="projectpath"
```

then

```
python .\"testscriptpath"
```

Now this week I started seeing this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError : No Module named 'tests'
```

I tried the solution of adding a blank `__init__.py` file, but it didn't help.

I am looking for a solution to generate XML report files.

Below is the code:

```
import unittest
import allure
import xmlrunner
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from tests.common import WICSUtils
from tests.common.GenericUtils import wics_select_by_visible_text, wics_utils_click, wics_select_by_index, \
    wics_utils_get_text
from tests.icc.ICC_Common_Methods import search_by_offender_id_icc, make_initial_decision, \
    go_to_inmate_classification_report, go_to_job_submitter_screen_and_submit_report, \
    refresh_job_queue_until_job_finished


class ICCInmateInitialClassification(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        # Get new driver instance
        global myDriver
        global emailAddress
        global userFolder

        myDriver = GenericUtils.get_new_driver_instance()
       
    @allure.step("Logging into WICS")
    def test_01_logging_into_WICS(self):
        global emailfolderforreports
        emailfolderforreports = "Reports"
        WICSUtils.loginToWICS(myDriver, WICSUtils.Environment.UAT1, test)
        expectedTitle = "ODSP590 - My Landing Page"
        actualTitle = WICSUtils.get_page_main_title(myDriver)
        GenericUtils.wics_assertion_is_substring(expectedTitle, actualTitle, myDriver)

      @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        WICSUtils.logOutWICS(myDriver)
        myDriver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # main method to run xmlrunner to produce xml report in test-reports folder
    with open('../../../test-results/ICC_R001_Inmate_Initial_Classification.xml', 'wb') as output:
        unittest.main(
            testRunner=xmlrunner.XMLTestRunner(output=output),
            failfast=False, buffer=False, catchbreak=False)
```

Below is the error stack trace:

```
PS C:\Users\VellaSR\PycharmProjects\wics-selenium-scripts> python .\tests\icc\High\ICC_R001_Inmate_Initial_Classification.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\tests\icc\High\ICC_R001_Inmate_Initial_Classification.py", line 8, in <module>
    from tests.common import WICSUtils
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tests'
```

Comment: Can you place more of your code here (as code not as a screen shot)?

Comment: i am trying to put my code here but it says too much text

Comment: Then you need to cut it down [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: i added the code in the main post

Comment: Please include the traceback in your post as formatted text, not as a screenshot. Also the code shown has a syntax error... you must have left out or changed parts in pasting it here. Please make sure you test the exact code you present here, even if it's trimmed down from your actual code (which, usually, it should be).

Comment: you mean error traceback?

Comment: Yes, the error traceback. Code and textual output should be shown as text, [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). Also unless I'm mistaken, your code still has an indentation error.

Comment: added the error stack trace

Comment: Your code as shown still doesn't run... but as to your actual question, have you opened a new PowerShell since your code last worked correctly? If so, have you set your path again?

Comment: Well Just now I opened CMD and set the python path there and then ran the same commands what i used to run earlier in pycharm terminal guess what
voila it started working !!!

not sure whats wrong with pycharm terminal also i tried windows powershell over there also it was showing same module not found error

but why it worked in CMD??

Comment: In *any* shell, setting your Python path that way only affects that particular session of that particular shell. To set or add to your Python path permanently, methods will vary depending on which shell you're talking about.

Comment: I am talking about pycharm terminal shell which shows PS 
in that it didnt worked , earlier it was not showing any module not found error
now its showing that error when i run the command
but in CMD its working perfectly also generating xml test results

Answer (score 0):

In order to make Python resolves all your relative imports, you must execute your script from the root working directory.

In your case, for example, the root is `wics-selenium-scripts`. You need to go there with your terminal, and then execute `python path/to/your/script.py`, e.g. `python tests\icc\High\scriptName.py`

Comment: I tried doing that but it shows some error

Comment: What is `some error`?

Comment: it shows this error

Comment: PS C:\Users\VellaSR\PycharmProjects\wics-selenium-scripts\tests\icc\High> python wics-selenium-scripts\tests\icc\High\ICC_R001_Inmate_Initial_Classification.py
C:\Program Files\Python374\python.exe: can't open file 'wics-selenium-scripts\tests\icc\High\ICC_R001_Inmate_Initial_Classification.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Re-read my answer. "You need to go there with your terminal", so that your terminal should show `PS C:\Users\VellaSR\PycharmProjects\wics-selenium-scripts>`

Comment: tried that and still error

PS C:\Users\VellaSR\PycharmProjects\wics-selenium-scripts> python .\tests\icc\High\ICC_R001_Inmate_Initial_Classification.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\tests\icc\High\ICC_R001_Inmate_Initial_Classification.py", line 8, in <module>
    from tests.common import WICSUtils
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tests'

Comment: any fix for this please?

Comment: Well Just now I opened CMD and set the python path there and then ran the same commands what i used to run earlier in pycharm terminal guess what
voila it started working !!!

not sure whats wrong with pycharm terminal also i tried windows powershell over there also it was showing same module not found error

but why it worked in CMD??